# zip_longest on Array with lists of the same length. Understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, splat

I have an Array which contains a few lists all the same length. All those lists need to be written in a .csv-file. Using a piece of code i have found it works pretty well. Here the code:

```
ag=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

export_data = zip_longest(*ag, fillvalue = '') 

with open('motion_profile.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(("m","ax","ay","az","sx","sy","sz"))
    wr.writerows(export_data)  
myfile.close()
```

I understand the basic concept of `zip` and `zip_longest` when i have two arrays which i use it on. But i just can't wrap my head around what it does with a single array like here `export_data = zip_longest(*ag, fillvalue = '')`

What exactly happens to `ag` if i use `zip` or `zip_longest` on it?

Since i don't have two arrays what does it zip against?

`zip_longest` is being applied to each list in `ag` hence the `*`. That is how far I have gotten with it.

Could anyone walk me through that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip()` does not necessarily take two arrays; it takes an arbitrary number of arrays (iterables) [as positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Taking this in smaller steps,

- `*ag` unpacks the nested list.  Note that it only unpacks "one level down."  You're effectively left with 4 lists, `[1, 2, 3]`, ... `[10, 11, 12]`, as disparate elements that will become positional arguments.
- From there, `zip()` behaves as expected (you're passing it multiple unpacked lists).

You can see the equivalency:

```
>>> i, j, k = zip(*ag)

>>> i
(1, 4, 7, 10)
>>> k
(3, 6, 9, 12)

>>> i2, j2, k2 = zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12])
                #     |_______|_______|________|
                #                 i2

>>> i2
(1, 4, 7, 10)
>>> k2
(3, 6, 9, 12)
```

In other words, those four sub-lists are passed as four positional arguments to `zip()`.

In terms of the call syntax, `itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)` is pretty similar; it just has one keyword argument tacked on to the end.  The way in which the sub-lists are passed is effectively the same.